# Do you have to run nodetool repair on every node?

Tags: maintenance, cassandra

Do you have to run `nodetool repair` on every node in a cluster, or do you only need to run it on one node, and from there Cassandra will take care of the rest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In looking through the documentation, I am having a hard time finding a reference for this, but the short answer is "yes" you need to run `nodetool repair` on each node in your cluster.  The closest I can find is the [documentation on repairing nodes](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_repair_nodes_c.html) which suggests that you should not run repair on more than one node in your cluster at a time.

You can also run [repair](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsRepair.html) with the `-pr` flag, which limits the repair operation to the first token range that current node is responsible for.  This cuts down on the duplication of work when run on the remaining nodes.

Comment: So if I run with `-pr` on every node, will that cover the entire keyspace?

Comment: @2rs2ts Yes, if you run it with `-pr` on every node it will cover the entire keyspace(s).

Comment: Okay... I'm going to assume, then, that you are supposed to run it on every node but you can save time with the `-pr` flag.

Comment: I added some sources to the other answer.  This source is fairly clear: "The hard requirement for routine repair frequency is the value of gc_grace_seconds. Run a repair operation at least once on **each** node within this time period."  [Repairing Nodes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_repair_nodes_c.html)

Answer (score 9):

How it behaves depends on your configuration, what version of Cassandra you use, and how you run the repair command.

If you just run `nodetool repair` on a single node in a cluster it will repair all of the data (token ranges) that node is responsible for and also the other nodes that are responsible for that data.

So for example, if you were to run the `nodetool repair` command on a single node in a given cluster:

- If you are running a three node cluster with a replication factor of three all nodes will own all of the data and thus repairs will be performed for all nodes.
- If you are running a six node cluster with a replication factor of 2 the data will only be repaired on two of the six nodes.  The repair will need to be initiated on two more of the remaining four nodes.

That said, it's possible to define what hosts and data centers to perform repairs on using the `-hosts` and `-dc` flags.  Additionally if you use the `-pr` flag (which will only pick the first token range the node is responsible for) you will have to run `nodetool repair -pr` on **all** nodes in the cluster.

One other flag to keep in mind is the `-inc` flag, which was included in Cassandra 2.1.  This option will only repair new data (data that hasn't been previously repaired).  Be careful when relying on this, especially if you frequently delete data. ([more on this](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/more-efficient-repairs))

Something else to keep in mind is that the default way repairs are done in Cassandra can vary.  As of Cassandra 2.1 when running just `nodetool repair` it performs a full sequential repair by default.  You will want to look up what your version does.

For more reading on the topic:

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/repair-in-cassandra

Comment: the only good answer here

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have to run on each individual node. `nodetool repair` runs on set of nodes, which is clearly stated in the [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsRepair.html).

You can limit the nodes or part of data on which you want to run repair. For example, you can provide `-pr` option for partitioner range, range for which node is responsible, but this will have to be run on whole cluster. But if you chose `-local`, then the nodes in local datacenter of node will get repaired.

Comment: Running `nodetool repair` on a single node is not sufficient to repair all replicated data on all nodes in all configurations.  Running `nodetool repair` on a single node will only repair data replicated on that node.  (Adding the `-pr` option limits the repair to data for which this node is the first replica.)  But if you have data in your cluster that is not replicated on this node, then you must run `nodetool repair` on additional nodes.

Comment: "If the -pr option is not specified, Cassandra repairs all replica ranges that fall within the responsibility of the node." [nodetool repair docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsRepair.html)  (I.e. does not repair data for which this node is not responsible for replicating.)  "The hard requirement for routine repair frequency is the value of gc_grace_seconds. Run a repair operation at least once on **each** node within this time period."  [Repairing Nodes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_repair_nodes_c.html)